# COUNTIF with IFERROR in the range

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A             B             C
1       50           20           =IFERROR(A1/B1,"") = 2.5
2       60            0           =IFERROR(A2/B2,"") = ""
3       80            0           =IFERROR(A3/B3,"") = ""
4       10           50           =IFERROR(A4/B4,"") = 0.2
5
6                  COUNT:            2
7
```

In **Cell C6** I want to count the number of items in the list which are not " " according to **Column C**.

I tried to do this with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4;"<>""")
```

However, this formula gives me back the value **4** instead of **2**.
Therefore, I guess the issue is related to the IFERROR functions which I use in **Column C**.

Do you have any idea how I have to change the COUNTIF formula to only count the cells without " "?

---

I know - *in this specific case* - I could solve the issue by using the COUNTIF formula over Column B. However, I would prepfer a solution that goes over **Column C**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `COUNTIF` use `SUMPRODUCT` as

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C4<>"")*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky.  I usually count the blanks using `COUNTBLANK` and take that away from the total count

```
`=COUNTA(D1:D4)-COUNTBLANK(D1:D4)`
```

[image: Count blanks cells]

Also because in this case your output is the result of a division you could use `=COUNTIF(D1:D4,">-1")` to count everything with a value zero or above.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/#countif-blank

In your example, the formula could be

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4;"")
```